# Google Cloud flowers tutorial Apache Beam pipeline error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I've been stuck on this for hours and can't seem to figure out what's going on. Basically, I'm going through the Google Cloud tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/flowers-tutorial) and when I get to the step to preprocess data, it keeps giving me an Apache Beam pipeline error below...which I don't understand at all. I'm not even sure what it's referring to. It took forever to correctly install my Apache Beam instance within the virtual environment, but somehow it seems that it didn't install correctly...

The error:

```
(cmle-env) MACBOOKPRO:flowers USERNAME$ python trainer/preprocess.py \
python trainer/preprocess.py \
>     --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
    --input_dict "$DICT_FILE" \
>     --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
    --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv" \
>     --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
    --output_path "${GCS_PATH}/preproc/eval" \
>     --cloud
    --cloud
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 490, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 486, in main
    run(arg_dict)
  File "trainer/preprocess.py", line 393, in run
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
  File "/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/cloudml-samples-master/flowers/cmle-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 104, in __init__
    'Received : %r', options)    
ValueError: ('Parameter options, if specified, must be of type PipelineOptions. Received : %r', <apache_beam.options.pipeline_options.PipelineOptions object at 0x11639ec50>)
shell_session_update
Saving session.../bin/date +%s

...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
/usr/bin/find "$SHELL_SESSION_TIMESTAMP_FILE" -mtime -1d

[Process completed]
```

And at this point it just hangs and I can't quit anything (i.e. the CLI prompt doesn't come back.)

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Comment: It seems like you're providing options to the `Pipeline` constructor that are not of the type `PipelineOptions`. Could you add your code where you construct the `pipeline_options` used in `with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:`

Comment: The thing is, I didn't write any of that code - it's what came with the tutorial! Surely the error is in how it's being implemented rather than the code itself...?

Comment: It seems like the `PipelineOptions` imported in `preprocess.py` is not the same as the `PipelineOptions` imported in the apache beam `pipeline.py`. Which version of apache_beam are you using?

Comment: The tutorial's [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers) includes a sample.sh file, are you able to run it successfully? It does require you to have a bucket named ${PROJECT}-ml.